# The Outlook Inbox Filter doesn't work....why not?

Tags: powershell, outlook, inbox

Instead of showing ReceivedTime only for Inbox items for the last two days, this shows for all Inbox items, why?

```
$objOutlook = new-object -comobject Outlook.Application
$namespace = $objOutlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$InboxFolder = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder(6)

$DateYest = (Get-Date).AddDays(-2)
$InboxFolder | where-object {$_.ReceivedTime -gt "$DateYest"}
ForEach ($MailItem in $InboxFolder) {
write-host $MailITem.ReceivedTime
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted doesn't return any inbox items. As written you are filtering your one inbox by it's nonexistent `RecievedTime` property. My assumption is your example is missing the `.Items` property. If you add `.Items` to your filter as it stands it wouldn't be captured to a variable or passed down the pipe so it would output directly to the console. However when written properly the filter works fine.

```
$objOutlook = new-object -comobject Outlook.Application
$namespace = $objOutlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$InboxFolder = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder(6)

$DateYest = (Get-Date).AddDays(-2)
$filteredItems = $InboxFolder.items | where-object {$_.ReceivedTime -gt $DateYest}
foreach ($MailItem in $filteredItems) {
    write-host $MailITem.ReceivedTime
}
```

or

```
$objOutlook = new-object -comobject Outlook.Application
$namespace = $objOutlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$InboxFolder = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder(6)

$DateYest = (Get-Date).AddDays(-2)
$InboxFolder.items |
    Where-Object {$_.ReceivedTime -gt $DateYest} |
        ForEach-Object {
            write-host $_.ReceivedTime
        }
```

Comment: The explanation is worth almost as much as the solution ! Many thanks !